# How do you execute python code and open html page in a function (flask)?

Tags: python, html, flask

```
@app.route('/login', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
if request.method == 'POST':
    user = request.form['nm']
    password = request.form['pwd']
    if user_add(user, password) == True:
        return url_for('hello', name = user)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('incorrect'))
  @app.route('/classes', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def classes(name):
    file.write(#input from classes.html)
```

I want to go to the login function and if user_add is True, I want to execute the classes function and open classes.html used by this function. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You asked for 2 things here:

1. How to call the classess function? (This is a view function)
2. Open classes.html file

For question 1, simply use `redirect` from flask.

```
from flask import redirect
if user_add(user, password) == True:
    return redirect('classes')
```

Then for question 2, inside the classes view use `render_template` from flask

```
from flask import render_template
@app.route('/classes', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def classes(name):
    return render_templates('classes.html')
```